# Uncompress files for each subdirectory of each folder

Tags: python

I have a tree of directories which structure looks like this :

**-folder1**
-------subfolder1
----------------------zipfile
-------subfolder2
----------------------compressed bzfile
**-folder2**
-------subfolder1
----------------------compressed bzfile
-------subfolder2
----------------------compressed bzfile

And so on..

My goal is to uncompress each zipfile for all the subdirectories of the folders 1, 2, 3 [...], 10.

The algorithm would be this one but I'm stuck..

```
import tar
for each folder
    for each subfolder
        tarfile.open(each_file)
        tar.extractall(in_the_subdirectory_of_the_tarfile)
        tar.close
```

Would you have any ideas to make it work ?
Thanks !

Comment: you can walk over subdirectories using `os.walk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import tar
import os

path = "."

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        file = os.path.join(root, name)
        tarfile.open(file)
        tar.extractall(in_the_subdirectory_of_the_tarfile)
        tar.close
```

Comment: Great, thank you it works ! Just a question : do you know how to make it to uncompress the bz files **into their native subdirectory** ? Thanks !

Comment: You can obtain the native subdirectory like this dir = os.path.dirname(file) then you just run tar.extractall with the dir as parameter